# Memory-leak when rewriting data (C++)

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Ive problem with my code (C++)causing memory leak ( i belive). Basically i want it to do the following: take data from user untill he writes "stop" and make heap out of that data. I guess that I'm missing a removal of booked memory at some point but i dont know how to fix it. Also the code seems to be working in code::blocks but it crashes in Dev C++.

```
cout<<"Enter data to heap if u wanna stop write stop."<<endl;

int *w1=new int[1];

int kek=0;

    while(true)

{
    cin>>*(w1);

    if (!cin)
        {                                        /// the "stop"" thingy
            w1=w1-kek;
            cout<<"heap:  "<<endl;
            for (int i=0;i<kek;i++)
                {
                    cout<<" "<<*w1<<" ";
                    w1++;
                }
            break;
        }
int *w2=new int[2+kek];
w1=w1-kek;                                         
        for(int t=0;t<kek+1;t++)          ///rewriting data to new chunks of memory          
            {

                *w2=*w1;
                w2++;
                w1++;
            }
delete[]w1;                               ///releasing old ones ( i think something is wrong here)   
w1=w2;                                        
kek++;
w1=w1-kek-1;                                 
int kekkeeper=kek;
for(int l=log(kek)/log(2);l>0;l--)            /// heapnig things up

        {

            if(*(w1+kekkeeper/2)>*(w1+kekkeeper)) swap (*(w1+kekkeeper/2),*(w1+kekkeeper));
            else break;
            kekkeeper=kekkeeper/2;
        }    
    w1=w1+kek+1;
    w2=NULL;
    delete[]w2;


    }
```

Comment: It's still hard nowadays to have speaking variable names...

Comment: `w2=NULL; delete[]w2;` Doenst make sense. delete w2 before you set it to nullptr.

Comment: *Better* indendation, please. Code should not look like a sine wave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you changed both pointers w1 and w2 in the following loop

```
for(int t=0;t<kek+1;t++) {
  *w2=*w1;
   w2++;
   w1++;
}
```

so you must reset this modification for each pointer before deleting it.
the reseting instruction for w1 can look like this

```
w1=w1-(kek+1);
delete[]w1;
```

and for w2 like this

```
w2=w2-kek;
delete[]w2;
```

finally you must move the allocation of w1 into the while loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However i didn't do all the things you told me to but indeed i was deleting wrong area of memory at this line "delete[]w1;" beacause i didn't move back pointer w1.

Answer (score 2):

look at the last tow lines
you set w2 to NULL before your delete it

Comment: lol, yes. Sadly though, still something that should have been caught by OP debugging before posting here:(

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out i wasn't sure about these lines however deleting the memory that is pointed by w2 before setting it to NULL doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: I could fix the bug in your version, if you are still interested I can post it :-)

Comment: I'd be very happy to see that if possible !